# Running Python Script/application in Windows Phone 8

Tags: c#, windows-8, windows-phone-8, windows-phone, ironpython

I want to run the Skeinforge slicer program written in Python inside my Windows Phone 8 C# application. I have determined that I should probably use IronPython to do this, I have already determined that I can run Skeinforge inside the ipy.exe terminal I got when I installed IronPython. My problem though is that I am struggling to figure out how to host and run a Python script with IronPython inside Windows Phone 8. I have also already managed to get a simple hello world script running inside a Desktop Windows Forms application that transfers the applications console output to the Debug console with the following code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;

using IronPython.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Scripting.Hosting;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            DebugWriter debugW = new DebugWriter();
            Console.SetOut(debugW);
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            TextWriter tw = new StreamWriter("Test.py");
            tw.Write(scriptBox.Text);
            tw.Close();

            try
            {
                var ipy = Python.CreateRuntime();
                dynamic test = ipy.UseFile("Test.py");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("Error: " + ex.Message);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And this is the DebugWriter:

```
class DebugWriter : TextWriter
{
    private StringBuilder content = new StringBuilder();

    public DebugWriter()
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("Writing console to debug");
    }

    public override void Write(char value)
    {
        base.Write(value);
        if (value == '\n')
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(content.ToString());
            content = new StringBuilder();
        }
        else
        {
            content.Append(value);
        }
    }

    public override Encoding Encoding
    {
        get { return System.Text.Encoding.UTF8; }
    }
}
```

I have no idea how to even add the IronPython libraries to my Windows Phone 8 application though as the standard libraries won't import. I have though tried compiling the apparently now defunct Windows Phone 7 libraries with the master source code and I can import these libraries, but I get absolutely no response on the debug terminal when I try to run my hello world script.

Do any of you have any idea how to get this woring in Windows Phone 8, if you know how to do this in Windows 8/Metro/RT then that would also probably work for WP8.

UPDATE:
I have looked at the debug output again and I seem to get this error when trying to use the WP7 libraries to run a hello world script:

```
A first chance exception of type 'System.NotImplementedException' occurred in Microsoft.Scripting.DLL
Error: The method or operation is not implemented.
```

Comment: Iron Python doesn't support Windows Phone 8 - it's as simple as that. Also, if a library supports WP8, that **does not** mean it automatically supports Win8/RT.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get Skeinforge running on a modified version of IPY. You can get the source for my application here: http://skeinforgewp8.codeplex.com/